# Реализовать ассемблерную вставку в с++ (определение интеграла методов средних квадратов)

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Есть код на с++, который находит интеграл методом средних прямоугольников:

```
    int a;
    int b;
    float step;

    cout << "Enter a:" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter b:" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter step: " << endl;
    cin >> step;

    float sum = 0;
    float result = 0;
    clock_t start, end;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i <= (b - a) / step; i++) {
        sum += cos(((a + i*step) + (a + (i+1)*step))/2);
    }
    result = sum * step;
    end = clock();

    cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
    cout.precision(12);
    cout << "Execution time: " << ((float) end - start) /
    ((float) CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << endl;
```

Нужно сделать ассемблерную вставку, которая реализовала бы тоже самое. Нужна реализация на ассемблере именно этого участка кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (b - a) / step; i++) {
        sum += cos(((a + i*step) + (a + (i+1)*step))/2);
    }
    result = sum * step;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать цикл и само тело цикла на ассемблере. Пробовал многие варианты, но не получилось. Поэтому прошу вашей помощи. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Скомпилируйте компилятором С++ и посмотрите на ассемблерный листинг. Выпирающие углы :) обработайте напильником...

Comment: Могу посоветовать онлайн-компилятор в язык ассемблера https://gcc.godbolt.org/. По сути это оболочка над различными компиляторами (на выбор, по умолчанию GCC).

Comment: Только при ассемблировании C+++кода придётся дополнительно реализовать и используемые функции стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для IA-32:

```
int i = 0, two = 2;

__asm {
    fild b
    fisub a
    fdiv step 
    fldz
L1: fild i 
    fcomi st(0), st(2) 
    ja L2
    fmul step
    fiadd a
    fld st(0) 
    fadd step
    faddp st(1), st(0)
    fidiv two
    fcos
    faddp st(1), st(0)
    inc i
    jmp L1
L2: fincstp
    fstp st(1)
    fmul step
    fstp result
}
```